# How set a htmlarea to some specific textarea ,instead of all textarea

Tags: php, drupal, jhtmlarea

I have a drupal site.

And i have intsalled a htmlarea module and it worksfine.

Now all textarea in the form changed into htmlarea.

How is possible to change only some particular textarea to htmlarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a code snippet in htmlarea.js,which gets while downloading htmlarea zip

```
 $('textarea[@editor="xinha"]').each(
```

change this section to

```
  $('textarea[@name="description"]').each(
```

where **'description'** is the name of the particular textarea, which we need to change